# how include fonts in project on the angular?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I cant include fonts in my project.on the Internet I have not found a guide how to do this.That's how I connected them:

```
@import "./fonts/fontello/css/fontello.scss"


@font-face
    font-family: 'latoblack'
    src: url('/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.eot')
    src: url('/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url:'/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.woff' format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/LatoBlack/lato-black.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latobold'
    src: url('/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot')
    src: url('/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url:'/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.woff' format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/LatoBold/lato-bold.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latoitalic'
    src: url('/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot')
    src: url('/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url:'/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.woff' format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latolight'
    src: url('/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.eot')
    src: url('/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url:'/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.woff' format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/LatoLight/lato-light.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal

@font-face
    font-family: 'latoregular'
    src: url('/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.eot')
    src: url('/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url:'/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.woff' format('woff'),
         url('/fonts/fonts/LatoRegular/lato-regular.ttf') format('truetype')
    font-weight: normal
    font-style: normal
```

I have no err in cmd but fonts not workfonts do not change in the browse!Can write how include fonts in angular?
[image]
[image]
Screenshots shows the structure of the folders.

I try include folder fonts in assets and include in project font but i have err:

```
 @font-face {
  23 |     font-family: 'latoitalic';
> 24 |     src: url('../assets/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot');
     |         ^
  25 |     src: url('/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), {
  26 |          url:'/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.woff' format('woff'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats how i must do `/assets/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot`

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the `fonts` folder in the `asserts` of `.angular-cli.json`?

Make sure to include it in your `.angular-cli.json` as:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "assets": [
        './apps/fonts'
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: `"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico",
        "./app/fonts"
      ],`  Here so I added in '.angular-cli.json'.But not work.

Comment: You need to give path as `url('/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot')`  you don't have to specify `assets`

Comment: I add font like `/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot` but it still not work:(.Its not work with img in sass.I try `background-image: url("/img/layer-24.png")`But this also does not work

Comment: sorry its works `/assets/fonts/LatoItalic/lato-italic.eot`

Comment: Great.can you please accept the aswer. Would be great help!